# concatenate two zipped byte arrays

Tags: java, performance, java-8, zip, gzip

Hello I am having a map reduce job which merges different byte arrays together based on some grouping algorithm.

I tried zipping each array individually using Java Deflater but when I try to extract the resultant zipped byte array, it is only the first sub array that I extracted.

Is it it possible byte arrays once zipped to be just concatenated and then extracted or this is not the case ?

What I want is:

```
byte array1[] - zip
byte array2[] - zip
byte array3[] = append(array1,array2).
unzip resulting array3.
```

When I unzip it I receive only array 1.

Comment: That's not the case. You can't concatenate zipped data in form of a ``byte[]``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zip files are structured and they contain not only "zipped" data. For each entry in the file there is a local header and corresponding entry data. At the end of the file there is a *central directory* which enumerates all zip entries contained in the archive and the offsets where these start. You may think of a zip file roughly like this:

```
[entry-header,data][entry-header,data].....[central dir with entry meta-data][end-of-file]
```

You cannot just "merge" two zip files as byte arrays because the result will not be a valid zip.

Comment: I guess there is not alternative zipping mechanism. The problem is the the I am using Java 8 streaming API with collector. Everytime I insert in the accumulator I do zip potentially I can use ZippedOutputstream but when I start combining the items I will have to unzip before I zip again in order to combine the two arrays. Right ?

Comment: As far as I understand your question - yes, this is right. You can't concatenate zipped data as f1sh already pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

This could be done more efficiently with simple loops, but if one were determined to use java 8's `Stream`, they might try something like this.  I haven't tested it, but assuming there a function to decompress a single byte array into another byte array:

```
byte[] combined = Stream.of(array1, array2, array3) // or use Stream.builder
    .map(arr -> decompress(arr))
    .flatMapToInt(a -> IntStream.range(0,a.length).map(i -> a[i]))
    .mapToObj(i -> (byte) i)                        // boxes into a Byte
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), Bytes::toArray))
```

1. The pipeline starts with a `Stream<byte[]>`, containing compressed data
2. The `map()` converts each compressed `byte[]` to an uncompressed `byte[]`
3. The `flatMapToInt()` takes the bytes from each `byte[]` and creates a single contiguous stream of primitive ints
4. Each `byte` is only an `int` momentarily as in the next stage it converts it into a boxed `Byte` in the `mapToObj()`
5. The stream ends in a collection to `List<Byte>` which is then passed to guava's `Bytes.toArray()` to convert it into one contiguous byte array of decompressed data.