# Parse string with java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, guava, java-stream

I have ip address string like "192.168.1.1". Is it possible to parse string using java 8 streams and get primitive byte array as a result. Currently i have code

```
Arrays.stream(address.split("\\."))
      .map(UnsignedBytes::parseUnsignedByte)
      .toArray(Byte[]::new);
```

where is UnsignedBytes is guava class which return byte, but this code return Byte[] not byte[]

**Update:**
Yes, i read about why ByteStream class is absent.
My question is about, is it possible to get byte array using java-8 streams, without overhead such as create intermediate list.

Comment: The only way I could possibly conceive of doing that would be to write a custom collector.  That could work, but it might be tricky.

Comment: You might collect to a list and use guava's `Bytes.toArray` to get a primitive array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java 8, is there a ByteStream class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459683/in-java-8-is-there-a-bytestream-class)

Comment: see the final `collect` in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36613808/3487617

Comment: Frankly, this is an interesting intellectual effort, but this is the kind of situation where a plain old simple for loop is much simpler and readable. And you won't parallelize that stream, so it doesn't even have that advantage.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use [Java's InetAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) class.

```
 InetAddress i = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1");
 byte[] bytes = i.getAddress();
```

Comment: I like this answer, but the javadoc says *The result is in network byte order: the highest order byte of the address is in `getAddress()[0]`*. I think you need to reverse the byte array to suit OP's need.

Comment: @Bohemian Not sure what order the OP wants. The code above has 192 in `bytes[0]`, 168 in `bytes[1]`, and so on. Which makes sense to me.

Comment: I must have been thinking bits (where 0 is the "last" bit). This is fine!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Pattern.splitAsStream(CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-) use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` in a collector:

```
byte[] bytes = Pattern.compile("\\.")
        .splitAsStream(address)
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(
                ByteArrayOutputStream::new,
                ByteArrayOutputStream::write,
                (baos1, baos2) -> baos1.write(baos2.toByteArray(), 0, baos2.size())
        )
        .toByteArray();
```

Collect code adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32470838/3255152.

Comment: I like this answer better because it fits in the theme of the question, and would be useful outside of just parsing IP addresses.